# Is it possible/feasible to decompile a program written in C++ to C?

Tags: decompilation, c++, c

I've not seen a lot of material on this. I've seen people attempting to bring a C++ program back to C++ code, and claiming how hard it is, but C code from C++ program? I don't know.

If it is *possible,* what obstacles would be in the way? If *impossible,* what particular features make it so?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @RolfRolles I am more familiar with C. I am not certain the exact language this program was written in, but others suggest it was C++. If possible, I'd like to stay within my realm of knowledge. If doing this is not possible... I will simply have to expand my realm.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking whether it's possible for an automated decompiler to produce C code as output for a given C++ input binary (rather than producing C++ code as output), the answer is that most decompilers are going to do this anyway, and are not going to give you a choice as to which language they produce as output. Machine-code decompilers generally produce a C-like pseudocode, which, in general, cannot be immediately recompiled to C code. A better question would be "to what extent can the C-like pseudocode produced by decompilers represent features of C++ that are not in C", to which the answer depends on the specific decompiler in question.

If you're asking whether it's possible to manually decompile a C++ program into a C program, the answer is yes. Just as you can take a program written in C++ and manually translate it into C, you can manually decompile a binary into any language you want. There's going to be a lot of manual work regardless of which language you choose to decompile the program into. Although C and C++ are not the same language, the first C++ compilers worked by translating C++ code into C code, and using a regular C compiler on the result (see: CFront https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront). You can simulate most C++ constructs in C, although it's going to be a lot more work than simply taking advantage of the features introduced by C++.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, yes.
Here, the problem is that you need to know well about the difference between c and c++ from the viewpoint of reversing, I suppose.
For example, the c++ classes is converted to assem codes like c structure, and the virtual table of a class is converted a first member of a structure and other functions is converted like a regular functions.
And the  pointer of c++ class is converted a certain register like a "ecx" register in x84 assem code.
If you know somethings like this,  you can decompile c++ program to c.